# Finding the Dimension of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U, W$ be the vector spaces. We let $U \times W$ be the set of all pairs
$(u, w)$ with $u \in  U$ and $w \in W$.  If $\dim(U) = n$ and $\dim(W)=m$, what is $\dim(U\times W)$? Exhibit a basis of $U\times W$ in terms of a basis for $U$ and a basis for $W$.

Comment: Please, show your work when you ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. For $u \in U$ and $w \in W$, we can write 
$$ (u,w) = (u,0) + (0,w) \in U \times W $$
Now express both $u$ and $w$ in the given bases. Can you see a basis for $U \times W$?